# Android Login Page crashes after I click on login button

Tags: php, android, json, android-asynctask

```
<?php

class DB_Functions {

    include 'config.php'
    private $db;
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $this->db = new DB_Connect();
        $this->db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }

    /**
     * Storing new user
     * returns user details
     */
    public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
        $uuid = uniqid('', true);
        $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");
        // check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            // get user details 
            $uid = mysqli_insert_id(); // last inserted id
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
            // return user details
            return mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get user by email and password
     */
    public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'") or die(mysqli_error());
        // check for result 
        $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $salt = $result['salt'];
            $encrypted_password = $result['encrypted_password'];
            $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
            // check for password equality
            if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
                // user authentication details are correct
                return $result;
            }
        } else {
            // user not found
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if user exist or not
     */
    public function isUserExist($email) {
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT email from users WHERE email = '$email'");
        $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            // user exist 
            return true;
        } else {
            // user does not exist
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Encrypting password
     * @param password
     * returns salt and encrypted password
     */
    public function hashSSHA($password) {

        $salt = sha1(rand());
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
        $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
        $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
        return $hash;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypting password
     * @param salt, password
     * returns hash string
     */
    public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

        $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

        return $hash;
    }

}

?>
```

MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Button btnLogin;
    Button btnLinkToRegister;
    public EditText inputEmail;
    public EditText inputPassword;
    TextView loginErrorMsg;
    String email;
    String password;

    // JSON Response node names
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
    private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
        loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

        // Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View view) {
                email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                new GoOnline().execute();
            }
        });

        // Link to Register Screen
        btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    class GoOnline extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading route. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);

            // check for login response
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        

                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);

                        // Close Login Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in login
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }


    }
}
```

UserFunctions code:

```
public class UserFunctions {

    private JSONParser jsonParser;

    // Testing in localhost using wamp or xampp 
    // use http://10.0.2.2/ to connect to your localhost ie http://localhost/
    private static String loginURL = "http://192.168.1.33/polizerlogin/";
    private static String registerURL = "http://192.168.1.33/polizerlogin/";

    private static String login_tag = "login";
    private static String register_tag = "register";

    // constructor
    public UserFunctions(){
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
        // return json
        // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * function make Login Request
     * @param name
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
        // return json
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * Function get Login status
     * */
    public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        int count = db.getRowCount();
        if(count > 0){
            // user logged in
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Function to logout user
     * Reset Database
     * */
    public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        db.resetTables();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Logcat:

```
02-01 10:00:45.835: E/JSON(28424): <br />
02-01 10:00:45.835: E/JSON(28424): <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-parse-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
02-01 10:00:45.835: E/JSON(28424): <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'include' (T_INCLUDE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in C:\wamp\www\polizerlogin\DB_Functions.php on line <i>5</i></th></tr>
02-01 10:00:45.835: E/JSON(28424): <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
02-01 10:00:45.835: E/JSON(28424): <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
02-01 10:00:45.835: E/JSON(28424): <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0160</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>141040</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\polizerlogin\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
02-01 10:00:45.835: E/JSON(28424): </table></font>
02-01 10:00:45.839: E/JSON Parser(28424): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
02-01 10:00:45.847: E/AndroidRuntime(28424): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
02-01 10:00:45.847: E/AndroidRuntime(28424): Process: com.mumbaipolice.www, PID: 28424
02-01 10:00:45.847: E/AndroidRuntime(28424): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-01 10:00:45.847: E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
02-01 10:00:45.847: E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
02-01 10:00:45.847: E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
02-01 10:00:45.847: E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
02-01 10:00:45.847: E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-01 10:00:45.847: E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-01 10:00:45.847: E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-01 10:00:45.847: E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-01 10:00:45.847: E/AndroidRuntime(28424): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
02-01 10:00:45.847: E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at com.mumbaipolice.www.MainActivity$GoOnline.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:92)
02-01 10:00:45.847: E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at com.mumbaipolice.www.MainActivity$GoOnline.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
02-01 10:00:45.847: E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-01 10:00:45.847: E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-01 10:00:45.847: E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    ... 4 more
02-01 10:00:46.478: E/WindowManager(28424): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.mumbaipolice.www.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{26ba7806 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,232} that was originally added here
02-01 10:00:46.478: E/WindowManager(28424):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:375)
02-01 10:00:46.478: E/WindowManager(28424):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
02-01 10:00:46.478: E/WindowManager(28424):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
02-01 10:00:46.478: E/WindowManager(28424):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
02-01 10:00:46.478: E/WindowManager(28424):     at com.mumbaipolice.www.MainActivity$GoOnline.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:82)
02-01 10:00:46.478: E/WindowManager(28424):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
02-01 10:00:46.478: E/WindowManager(28424):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
02-01 10:00:46.478: E/WindowManager(28424):     at com.mumbaipolice.www.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:58)
02-01 10:00:46.478: E/WindowManager(28424):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761)
02-01 10:00:46.478: E/WindowManager(28424):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767)
02-01 10:00:46.478: E/WindowManager(28424):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-01 10:00:46.478: E/WindowManager(28424):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-01 10:00:46.478: E/WindowManager(28424):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-01 10:00:46.478: E/WindowManager(28424):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
02-01 10:00:46.478: E/WindowManager(28424):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-01 10:00:46.478: E/WindowManager(28424):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-01 10:00:46.478: E/WindowManager(28424):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
02-01 10:00:46.478: E/WindowManager(28424):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
02-01 10:01:34.850: I/Process(28424): Sending signal. PID: 28424 SIG: 9
```

My application crashes whenever i try to login or register through the application. Running Android 5.0.1 on win32 bit Eclipse ADT. Can someone point out where i'm going wrong?

EDIT: Using Firebase Login is much easier now.

Comment: It's right there in your stack trace: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
02-01 10:00:45.847: E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at com.mumbaipolice.www.MainActivity$GoOnline.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:92)`

Comment: @Karakuri : The root of the problem is actually at the PHP end of things. Look at the first lines of the logcat the OP posted. Something is wrong in the PHP and it's returning an HTML formatted error message. This subsequently breaks the attempt to create a JSONObject as it can't handle `<br`. This causes a knock-on effect including the NPE and ultimately a leaked window as I suspect the whole AsyncTask will crash as a result.

Comment: There is no such <br> tag in the code. How do I get rid of it? When I check it on phpchecker online, it shows the above code to be perfectly alright. How do I go about this? @Karakuri

Comment: @VivekPatani this is a PHP error, your server-side code have some error or warning that returns such string which is invalid JSON, you need to make sure your server side is OK, then move to mobile, you can call ur server-side url using a web browser, or any other tool, like postman, once you got ur response correctly, move to mobile

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming from your Logcat that the following is what's being returned from you server by the PHP code...

```
02-01 10:00:45.835: E/JSON(28424): <br />
02-01 10:00:45.835: E/JSON(28424): <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-parse-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
02-01 10:00:45.835: E/JSON(28424): <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'include' (T_INCLUDE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in C:\wamp\www\polizerlogin\DB_Functions.php on line <i>5</i></th></tr>
02-01 10:00:45.835: E/JSON(28424): <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
02-01 10:00:45.835: E/JSON(28424): <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
02-01 10:00:45.835: E/JSON(28424): <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0160</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>141040</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\polizerlogin\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
02-01 10:00:45.835: E/JSON(28424): </table></font>
```

Notice the following from line 3 above...

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'include' (T_INCLUDE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in C:\wamp\www\polizerlogin\DB_Functions.php on line <i>5</i>
```

I'm not much of a PHP programmer but that suggests to me there's a problem with line 5 of your PHP. That makes sense as it has an include directive...

```
include 'config.php'
```

As I said I don't do much with PHP but if you can find out why that line is wrong and fix it (plus perhaps put some error handling into the PHP code) then you should get valid results.

I can see you're testing for...

```
if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null)
```

...and...

```
String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
```

In that case, proper error handling at the PHP end should return valid JSON but with `KEY_SUCCESS` set to indicate an error. It's the server which is generating the HTML response and if you fix that then things should be fine.

You do have another serious flaw in your code however. In `doInBackground(...)` of your `AsyncTask` you're attempting to modify a `TextView` as follows...

```
loginErrorMsg.setText("");
```

...you can't touch any UI elements from the `doInBackground(...)` thread. The best thing would simply be to use `doInBackground(...)` to 'grab' the network response and then return it to `onPostExecute(...)` so it can handle it.